# How to determine the type of alias analysis required?

Tags: compiler-construction, code-analysis, static-analysis, static-code-analysis

Attached is a homework question whether content-sensitive and/or flow-sensitive analysis is required to see which values src can point to.
And it gives the definitions of the content-sensitive and flow-sensitive analysis, but how do you interpret whether it is content-sensitive (result depending on calling stack) or content insensitive (result not depending on calling stack) and flow sensitive (looking at every point in the program) and flow insensitive (looking at any point in the program execution) ?

[image: AliasAnalysis]

Answer (score -1):

Flow-sensitive and Context-insensitive analysis required.

At line 3, Flow-sensitive analysis ensures src only points-to actual argument of function call.  otherwise it may point-to local also.

In both contexts at 10 and 11, src points-to a.(context-insensitive analysis is sufficient)

Comment: But the description says, Context-sensitive analysis will check what's on the calling stack. And "a" is passed in from the external calling stack, wouldn't that make it context-sensitive? In contrast to "local", which is not passed in from an external stack

Comment: @user1095332, Context-sensitive means differentiating the calling contexts.                  differentiating Call from 10th line, 11th line.    Context-insensitive does not mean that it does not know what value is passed. It combines all values passed for analysis.

Comment: Calling stack is different from activation record.  Just to match call and return call stack is used